# Problema con un menu dinamico basado en MySQL y PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando imprimir un aside desde una talba en MySQL usando una relacion y un tipo, las paginas tipo 1 son menus desplegables y las de tipo 2 sub-menus, ambas relacionadas con una relacion, si hay una pagina tipo 1 con una relacion dada las paginas tipo 2 solo se imprimiran en las paginas tipos 1 con esa relacion.

```
<?php
require_once'../models/clase_menu.php';
require_once'header.php';
$instance = new Menu();
$paginast = $instance->Listar1();
$paginaso = $instance->Listar2();
$paginasv = $instance->Listar3();
?>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach($paginast as $tablap) { ?>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" 
        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <i class="<?php echo $tablap->enlace ?>" style="color:#e35f08;"></i>
        <span><?php echo $tablap->nombre ?></span>
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
       <h6 class="dropdown-header">Lista de Tablas:</h6>
       <?php foreach($paginaso as $tabla) { ?>
        <?php while ($tablap->relacion == $tabla->relacion) {?>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo $tabla->link ?>">
          <i  style="margin-right: 15px" class="<?php echo $tabla->enlace ?>">
          <?php echo $tabla->nombre ?>
         </i>
       </a>
     <?php }}} ?>
   </div>   
   </li>  
 </ul>


 <?php
 require_once 'footer.php'
 ?>
```

y este es el codigo de mi listado de menus, todos de la misma pagina, el problema es que el while regresa un loop infinito y no he podido revertir la situacion, alguna sugerencia? gracias por ver mi pregunta agradeceria alguna respuesta, saludos.

```
<?php
require_once 'clase_conexion.php';
class Menu
{
    public function Listar1(){
    try
     {
      $conexion = new Conexion();
      $con = $conexion->get_conexion();
      $sql = $con->query("SELECT ID, nombre, link, enlace, tipo, relacion, estatus FROM pagina WHERE tipo = 1 AND estatus = 1");
      $pagina = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      return $pagina;
     }catch(Exception $e)
      {
        die($e->getMessage());
        }

    }

  public function Listar2(){
    try
     {
      $conexion = new Conexion();
      $con = $conexion->get_conexion();
      $sql = $con->query("SELECT ID, nombre, link, enlace, tipo, relacion, estatus FROM pagina WHERE tipo = 2 AND estatus = 1");
      $pagina = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
      return $pagina;
     }catch(Exception $e)
      {
        die($e->getMessage());
      }      
  }

  public function Listar3(){
  try
   {
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $con = $conexion->get_conexion();
    $sql = $con->query("SELECT ID, nombre, link, enlace, tipo, relacion, estatus FROM pagina WHERE tipo = 3 AND estatus = 1 AND relacion = 3");
    $pagina = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
    return $pagina;
   }catch(Exception $e)
    {
      die($e->getMessage());
    }      
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Un bucle while no puede ser:

```
$b = 0;
$c = 0;
while( $b == $c )
{
    // Bucle infinito
}

while( $b <= $c )
{
    //Bucle Infinito
}
```

Para evitar esto debes decrementar o incrementar una de las variables para que se cumpla lo sentenciado dentro del bucle while.
Si la condicion para que se cumpla el while SIEMPRE se cumple pues siempre tendras un bucle infinito.

Tu codigo esta medio spagueti, por eso no te puedo dar una solucion mas detallada, pero anda por ahi.

Prueba cambiar el while por un IF, porque no me entero aun que hace el while ahi.